# not deleted embadded document mongo

Tags: mongodb, pull

I have this data:

```
db.school.find({})

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a897f6c49bf66c10a70ed0d"), 
    "first_name" : "Jaskaran", 
    "last_name" : "singh", 
    "age" : 30.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a897f6c49bf66c10a70ed0f"), 
    "first_name" : "Amrit", 
    "last_name" : "singh", 
    "age" : 31.0
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a897f6c49bf66c10a70ed0e"), 
    "first_name" : "Vikas", 
    "last_name" : "Sharma", 
    "age" : 31.0, 
    "Address" : {
        "Pincode" : 1234.0
    }
}
```

I want to delete pincode

$pull is not working !!

```
db.school.update(
{
    '_id':ObjectId("5a897f6c49bf66c10a70ed0e")
},
{ $pull: {
    Address: {
        Pincode:1    }    
} },
{ multi:true }
);
```

WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })

```
db.school.update({}, {$pull:{ "Address": {$elemMatch: {Pincode :1234 } }}})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$pull` is for array, whereas you try to manipulate a sub-document.

The way to do that is using `$unset`:

`db.school.update({"Address.Pincode" : 1234}, { $unset: { "Address.Pincode" : "" } })`

for pincode 1234. To remove each pincode:

`db.school.update({}, { $unset: { "Address.Pincode" : "" } })`

Comment: this is correct, Please let me know if i want to delete Address node ? from all the records.

Comment: this is not working  :( db.school.update({}, { $unset: { "Address" : "" } })